# mongodb 3.6 on FreeBSD 11.1 tools missing?

Tags: mongodb, freebsd

On FreeBSD with mongodb 3.6 I need to tansfer a mongodb database to another server. But I can't find the respective package or port. Ther is neiteher a mongodb36-tools package or port.

It seems like the port for mongodb36-tools has a bug and is therefore taken off the ports repo.

Can anyone confirm this? I there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the mongodb36-tools port is about to be added to the ports tree. Here's [an issue](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227198) on the FreeBSD Bugzilla.

You may either ping people on Bugzilla if they are working on merging it or use [the submitted patch](https://bz-attachments.freebsd.org/attachment.cgi?id=192095) and compile the port on your own. I guess the best idea is to ask about the state of affairs on Bugzilla.

Also, remember that you'll need to switch to the *latest* branch in pkg(8) in order to get the latest packages.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've noticed the issue, but I could hardly believe it.

I'm on quarterly with ports an packages on all of my servers. So latest is currently not an option.

Would you by any chance happen to know, where I can get the source tarball?

Comment: @LongHike Sure. I guess you may try to ask if it could be merged into the quarterly branch as soon as possible :)